# DrawerLayout: hide item on drawer open

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

Is possible, with a DrawerLayout to hide some items on the

```
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
```

I'm using a recyclerview with a RecyclerView.Adapter.

Comment: If you have a reference to the view, call view.setVisibility(View.GONE).

Need more info for a more specific answer

Comment: Agreed with @Gordak. We need more information on what exactly you want to hide. Please provide us with more code that we can comment on.

Comment: I'm using a recyclerview with a RecyclerView.Adapter<DrawerAdapter.ViewHolder>.

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference to that particular view, and set it's visibility to GONE.

view.setVisibility(View.GONE)

If you want to toggle the visibility of actionbar menu items, call invalidateOptionsMenu or supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(Compat Version) and perform a check in OnCreateOptionsMenu or o onPrepareOptionsMenu() i.e if the drawer is open or not.

Comment: I don't want to delete item, I want to disable it, for example with a darker text color and make it non clickable.

Comment: What item or view is this? You need to be more specific to get relevant answers.